# How to print a set of nested list as I need in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a nested containing values of different lengths as so:

```
[['cat', 123, 'yellow'],
['dog', 12345, 'green'],
[horse', 123456, 'red']]
```

I want to print them like this:

```
cat,   123,    yellow
dog,   12345,  green
horse, 123456, red
```

I have tried using pprint to achieve my aims with the following code:

```
for sub in master_list:

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(sub)
```

Where master is the nested list and sub the lists within it. This however gives me an output like so:

```
[
    'cat', 
    123, 
    'yellow'
],

[
    'dog', 
    12345, 
    'green'
],

[
    horse', 
    123456, 
    'red'
]
```

Is there a python module that allows me to relatively easily achieving what I want, without some sort of convoluted hack?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas can help.

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [['cat', 123, 'yellow'], ['dog', 12345, 'green'], ['horse', 123456, 'red']]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2
0   cat     123     yellow
1   dog     12345   green
2   horse   123456  red
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying...this has been the closest answer to what I need so far...the print representation of my dataframe is being abbreviated both width and height wise, represented by '...' on the screen...is there are a dataframe option to print the entire table do you know?

Comment: @gdogg371 See if this helps.
`with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df)`

Comment: yes that did it, thanks...i was using the options, but not as part of a with clause. the annoying/disappointing this is that could cannot left justify the column data from what i can see in the documentation, but otherwise this has been the best and easiest answer to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following code:

```
myLst = [['cat', 123, 'yellow'],
['dog', 12345, 'green'],
['horse', 123456, 'red']]

for subLst in myLst:
    print("\t".join([str(ele) for ele in subLst]))
```

Which is printing the output like so:

```
cat    123      yellow
dog    12345    green
horse  123456   red
```

In case you want to have "," too, just change the line

```
print("\t".join([str(ele) for ele in subLst]))
```

to

```
print(",\t".join([str(ele) for ele in subLst]))
```

And the complete thing as a one-liner:

```
print("\n".join([",\t".join([str(ele) for ele in subLst]) for subLst in myLst]))
```

Or in case you need a function:

```
def printLst(myLst):
    print("\n".join([",\t".join([str(ele) for ele in subLst]) for subLst in myLst]))
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments this is also a good use-case for the python `map` function. Which can be used in order to make everything shorter ;)

Comment: Maybe `",\t"` to get the comma.

Comment: You have a nice chance to use `map()` here: `print("\t".join(map(str, sub_list)))`

Answer (score 1):

Your concrete format wishescan be solved by printing with `ljust` to add the needed spaces:

```
data = [['cat', 123, 'yellow'],
        ['dog', 12345, 'green'],
        ['horse', 123456, 'red']]

# get the overall widest string as base for right-aligning them 
max_len = max( len(str(x)) for k in data for x in k) 

for inner in data:
    first = True
    for elem in inner[:-1]: # all but the last
        text = "{},".format(elem).ljust(max_len+2)
        print(text,end="")

    print(inner[-1]) # print last
```

Output:

```
cat,    123,    yellow
dog,    12345,  green
horse,  123456, red
```

Doku:

- [str.ljust(width[, fillchar])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) for left-justify in width
- [print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

---

Generally for formatting you can use the  [string format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to format your output to your liking:

```
for inner in data:
    first = True
    for elem in inner:
        if first:
            text = "{:<{}} ".format(elem,max_len+2)
            first = False
        else:
            text = ", {:<{}} ".format(elem,max_len+2)
        print(text, end="")
    print("")
```

Output:

```
cat      , 123      , yellow   
dog      , 12345    , green    
horse    , 123456   , red
```

The format string `"{:<{}} ".format(elem,max_len+2)` formats `element` rightaligned into `max_len+2` characters. The `first` thing is just to make your `,` not appear on the start of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
spacing = [max(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), d)) for d in zip(*data)]
for row in data:
    for i, elem in enumerate(row):
        e = str(elem) + (',' if i < len(row) -1 else '')
        print('{{:{}}} '.format(spacing[i]+1).format(e), end='')
    print()
```

## Results:

```
cat,      123,      orange  
elephant, 500000,   green   
horse,    123456.0, red
```

## Explanations:

`spacing` is defined by first gathering the maximum lengths of each "column" in your data.  We can group the columns by using:

```
zip(*data)
```

Which gives a transposed copy of your data like this:

```
('cat', 'elephant', 'horse'), 
(123, 500000, 123456.0), 
('orange', 'green', 'red')
```

Then we use the `map` function to apply the `len(str(x))` function over these columns:

```
(3, 8, 5),
(3, 6, 8), 
(6, 5, 3)
```

Then we just get the `max` of each column, combine everything in a list comprehension and return it as `spacing`:

```
spacing = [max(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), d)) for d in zip(*data)]
```

Then, while we loop through your data, we want to also `enumerate(row)` so we know which "column" we're working with.  `i` will give you the index of the column in addition to the actual `elem`.

After that, we assign a temporary `str` to append the comma if it's not the last element:

```
e = str(elem) + (',' if i < len(row) -1 else '')
```

This makes it a bit more readable then adding it as part of the format params.

Afterwards we use string formatting (or `e.ljust(spacing[i] + 1)` if you wish) to add the predefined maximum `spacing` based on the column.  Note we format the string twice by first escaping the outer curly brackets (`{{` and `}}`), so it can be in sequence:

```
'{{:{}}}.format(9).format(e)
# becomes
'{:9}'.format(e)
# becomes
'cat,     '
```

Note the use of `end=''` to make the print line continuous until the `row` has finished.  The `spacing[i] + 1` is to account for the added comma.

I must confess this might not be the most efficient way, but depending on what you're trying to achieve the solution can be markedly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
a = [['cat', 123, 'yellow'], ['dog', 12345, 'green'], ['horse', 123456, 'red']]

# Get the max length of string in the list
m = max([len(str(x)) for y in a for x in y])

# Use the format specifier in Python print function:
# Example: print '{:10s} {:3d}  {:7.2f}'.format('xxx', 123, 98)
# This prints : xxx        123    98.00
# We will create the string as {:6s}, here 6 is the length in our case and will be generated dynamically using 'm'

list(map(lambda x: print('\t'.join(list(map(lambda y:   str('{' + ':{m}s'.format(m=m) +'}').format(str(y)), x)))), a))
```

Output:

```
cat     123     yellow
dog     12345   green 
horse   123456  red
```

Comment: OMG this is so convoluted. Try this: `print('\n'.join('\t'.join('{:{width}}'.format(y, width=m) for y in x) for x in a))`

Answer (score 0):

Another way, given the nested list:

```
table = [['cat', 123, 'yellow'],
          ['dog', 12345, 'green'],
          ['horse', 123456, 'red']]
```

Using string methods:

```
for line in table:
  print("|", end='')
  for word in line:
    print (f" {word}".ljust(10) + "|", end='')
  print()
```

To get:

```
| cat      | 123      | yellow   |
| dog      | 12345    | green    |
| horse    | 123456   | red      |
```